# How make Android Studio use a default git email address?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, android-studio

Every time I do a commit I have to pick my user/email address from the dropdown menu in the 'Commit Changes' window.
Is there a way to make AS just pick the last one by default?

(I'm using AS 1.1.0 on OSX Yosemite)